# Blocks, Thread-safety, and NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, thread-safety, objective-c-blocks, nsmutabledictionary

I am adding objects to the same NSMutableDictionary from several different blocks in Objective-C.  These blocks are all callback functions for some other process; that is, they will be called at some undetermined point in the future when the original process has finished.

My concern has to do with possibility of the NSMutableDictionary being operated on by two different blocks at the same time.  I know that if the two blocks are run on different threads, then this is a legitimate concern.  I just want to know if blocks are always run on different threads, making this a concern whenever I use blocks at all.

Comment: It's a bit vague, from where do you call the blocks? Are you sure that you mean "another process" and not "another thread"?

Answer (score 3):

No, blocks are not always run on different threads. It depends entirely on what the block is and how you schedule it to be executed. Are you executing it yourself, adding it to an operation queue, using a GCD queue. The block could be run on any thread, including the main thread. You have control over whether it is run on the main thread or a background thread.

[ThreadSafety](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html)